# Starting an application with invisible console window

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have created a VB script which creates a shortcut to execute my test_application.exe. I want my application to run without a console. I am using following script to create the shortcut

```
Create_ShortCut "C:\Users\Me\bin\MyApplication.exe", "Desktop", "My-Test", "C:\Users\Me\bin" , 0, 1

Private Sub Create_ShortCut(TargetPath, ShortCutPath, ShortCutname, WorkPath, Window_Style, IconNum)
  Dim VbsObj
  Set VbsObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  Dim MyShortcut
  ShortCutPath = VbsObj.SpecialFolders(ShortCutPath)
  Set MyShortcut = VbsObj.CreateShortcut(ShortCutPath & "\" & ShortCutname & ".lnk")
  MyShortcut.TargetPath = TargetPath
  MyShortcut.Arguments = "127.0.0.1 5000 -exec=C:\Users\Another\other_application.exe"
  MyShortcut.WorkingDirectory = WorkPath
  MyShortcut.WindowStyle = Hidden
  MyShortcut.WindowStyle = 0
  MyShortcut.IconLocation = TargetPath & "," & IconNum
  MyShortcut.Save       
End Sub
```

I would like to start my application in invisible window and the other application to start in a normal window. When I create a shortcut like this I am not able to run my application in invisible mode. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Add a commndline argument to your app e.g --invisble, use that being there to hide the window. Then you can pass it in with the other arguments.

Comment: My application is not a Win32 application it is developed using minGW. Is there any other way by which I can make it invisible, maybe like a process which runs in the background ?

Comment: Not a clue mate, never used minGW

Comment: MinGW is a development environment. That doesn't say anything about whether or not you implemented your program as a Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

Don't target the console subsystem. If you do, expect to see a console. Instead target the GUI subsystem.